# how to create default value for for an object? PHP

Tags: php, class, object, inheritance, default

let's say I have a Human class which has the variable of $gender which doesn't have any value assigned into it. Human has a constructor with the parameter of age, gender, height and weight.

I have another class called Female which inheritance from Human but now the Female class is overriding the $gender variable with a string of `Female`.

When I create the object let's say `$f = new Female(12, 'female', 123, 40);`
How can I skip typing the female when creating the object?

I thought we need to create another new constructor in Female class which I did and in the Female class constructor's parameter I have `age, gender = 'female', height and weight` but this doesn't seem to work.

I tried leaving the gender part empty when creating the object or tried entering empty string such as `""`.

Can someone give me a hand please? Thanks a lot.

**Code for my human class**

```
class Human {
    protected $age = 0;   
    protected $gender;
    protected $height_in_cm;
    protected $weight_in_kg;

    function __construct($age, $gender, $heightCM, $weightKG)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->gender = $gender;
        $this->height_in_cm = $heightCM;
        $this->weight_in_kg = $weightKG;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGender()
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }
}
```

**Code for Female class**

```
require_once('Human.php');
class Female extends Human{
    protected $gender = 'female';

    function __construct($age, $gender = 'female', $heightCM, $weightKG)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->gender = $gender;
        $this->height_in_cm = $heightCM;
        $this->weight_in_kg = $weightKG;
    }
}

$f = new Female(12,'female',123,40);
echo "Your gender is ". $f->getGender()."<br>";
```

Comment: could you post your code please?

Comment: the whole idea is not correct ***(from my point of view)***, I mean if you want to classify `Human` to `Male` and  `Female` classes then why do you bother your self with a `$gender` parameter in the constructor, if i were you, i would omit that parameter and set it implicitly to *"male"* in the `Male` class and *"female"* in the `Female`

Comment: @Abdo Adel ah! I get what you mean, it'll be more of being redundant since I have to set default value in male and female why bother having the variable in human right? But then will have to set the getGender in both male and female instead of just set the getGender in Human.  Is there much a difference?  Sorry still in a long learning process.

Comment: what if @Dora wants to have more than two genders though? ;)

Comment: @morphatic Well I guess that the worst case here are 3 genders :D

Comment: @Dora No I didn't mean to omit the attribute `$gender` from the class, I meant to omit it from the constructor and set it manually in the constructor (`$this->gender = 'male'` in the `Male` class and the same for `Female`), this way you will avoid redundancy of specifying the gender every time you make an object and also the function `getGender` inherited from `Human` still works

Comment: @Abdo Adel oh ya right! but in this way, should I even think of not having a constructor in Human class at all? (if there's a 3rd gender :D that'll be another class anyways hah)

Comment: @Dora a 3rd gender could mean "not specified", should someone choose not to divulge that information if they are male or female. Sexual orientation has no bearing on this nor shouldn't. However having a 3rd option could or may prove to be beneficial somewhere down the road. *Just my 2 cents* ;-)

Comment: That's entirely left to the rest of the requirements,***if*** the constructors of `Male` and `Female` classes are very different, then it's better for each to have a separate constructor, ***if*** it's the same steps but only for the `$gender` then it's better to apply the elegant solution of @lxg down there (the one you accepted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply overwrite the constructor:

```
abstract class Human
{
    protected $age;

    protected $gender;

    protected $height;

    protected $weight;

    public function __construct($age, $gender, $height, $weight)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->gender = $gender;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->weight = $weight;
    }

    public function getGender()
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }
}

class Female extends Human
{
    public function __construct($age, $height, $weight)
    {
        parent::__construct($age, 'female', $height, $weight);
    }
}

$female = new Female(12, 170, 60);
echo $female->getGender();
```

Comment: ah! let me try this, I wasn't thinking of this at all.

Comment: This is not a good example. Where is `parent::__construct()` within Female constructor? You also do not need to repeat already declared properties in parent class.. just re-set them.

Comment: @Spooky what do you mean by reset them?

Comment: @Spooky: You're right about the redundant properties, removed them. What exactly do you mean with your first question?

Comment: @Dora: I had age, height and weight in the child class, too, which was redundant.

Comment: When You extend some class, and parent class does have constructor, child class MUST use parent::__construct() within it's own constructor..  Something like this `public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); /* child constructor code continues.. */ }` When I wrote re-set them, I was thinking about `$this->age = 'this and that';` etc.

Comment: @Spooky: *"child class MUST use parent::__construct()"* … whut? Neither the language itself nor any coding guidelines (AFAIK) demand that I use `parent::__construct` – although it certainly is a good idea to do so. And, btw, I did post an example that uses the parent constructor.

Comment: @ lxg ah! ok I get it now....this `parent::__construct` is more clean and not redundant right?

Comment: @Dora: yup. You could even pass the gender as a literal string: `parent::__construct($age, 'female', $height, $weight);` instead of declaring `private $gender = 'female'` in the child.

Comment: @lxg I wrote MUST because of later on issues he might expect as his code might grow huge.. You'll never know. When extending classes with constructors, always use/call parent constructor. Less headaches possible in the future.

Comment: @Dora: You’re welcome! Spooky: Yeah, I agree. I’ve fixed the code so that the better approach is used by default … no need to mislead people with a suboptimal solution.

Comment: @lxg ... And one more question.. I have noticed that the post is edited.. Now, the Human class became abstract.. with constructor? Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.. parent constructor (__construct method within Human class) is practically useless in this case now.

Comment: Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can have a constructor, and the constructor can be called (just like a public method) – even if the child doesn’t have an own constructor. (And yes, I did edit the code, see above, but `Human` was abstract all the time). Btw, see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c71c4ae20e8b9dda254b5169726fb40659b4326a

Comment: Bad practice. Not needed at all. Bunch of methods within abstract class and than extend as needed (if not `trait Human {}` instead )? - Why not, that's ok. Logically correct. constructor? Nope. I wouldn't do that in PHP with abstract classes.

Answer (score 4):

You can just set the value in the extended class:

```
// If it should be possible to instantiate the Human
// class then remove the "abstract" thing at set the
// "gender" property in the constructer
abstract class Human {
    protected $gender;
    protected $age;
    public function __construct($age) {
        $this->age = $age;
    }
}
class Female extends Human {
    protected $gender = "Female";
}
class Male extends Human {
    protected $gender = "Male";
}
```

Although this works, it really does not make that much sense. The class itself tells you what gender the human is, so you can just call `$human instanceof Female`.

```
$person = new Female(18);
if ($person instanceof Female) {
    echo "Person is female";
}
```

Comment: I think you’re missing the point. In the question, the OP outlined that gender, height and weight were also in the signature of the parent constructor, and OP had difficulties setting a default value for the gender parameter.

Comment: @lxg You may be right. I was under the impression that the question was about how to extend classes, and not simply about argument order and how to make them optional. I will leave my answer here in case it is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 3):

Simply override the constructor:

```
class Human {
     public function __construct($age, $gender, $height, $weight) {
     }
}

class Female extends Human {
    public function __construct($age, $height, $weight) {
         parent::__construct($age, 'Female', $height, $weight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, in you constructor

```
__construct($var, $gender="female", $var, $var){
//rest assignment
}
```

should do it

alternatively, use 3 param constructor with `female` already set

Comment: sorry for java way for writing constructor :P